# How do I get around this on iOS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I am working on an iOS mobile site.

I would like to add some content to the top of the page and at the same time scroll the page by the height of the content, so the user will not see the content until they scroll up.

Here's the code:

```
page.prepend( stuff );
window.scrollBy( stuff.height() );
```

This almost works, however there is a brief flash while the content is visible, before it is scrolled up out of view - I guess because adding the content to the DOM is intensive.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: is it not possible for you to have the content on the website by default instead of adding it with page.prepend()?

Comment: Nope, it needs to be added dynamically - this is part of an infinite scroller

Comment: Have you tried having it scroll down before adding the content?

Comment: you could also try using   window.location.hash = "ID";

Comment: Yeah reversing the order of the instructions doesn't help - again because the I think the prepend operation is intensive.

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but perhaps you could try pre-pending an empty DOM element, with 0px height, and overflow hidden first; then insert the new content within it (it wont show as the height is at 0px); then increase its height and scroll by 1px at a time to reveal it?

Comment: I'm with @BenBroadley, I would go ahead a make the dynamic element on pg load with it hidden then unhide it at the appropriate time.